# return error of 126 when compiling with idle 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

subprocess.call('/Users/siddarthkrishnan/Desktop/Lion.jpg', shell = True)
126 giving me this in python 3.5 return of 126.

Why is the file not opening? It is giving return error 126.

Comment: What does the `subprocess.call` print? It should have printed the error message if it failed (at least it does so on my system).

Comment: I think I found the cause of your problem. Your Windows Photo Gallery is probably not installed correctly. Please tell me what happens when you double-click the file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the path you pasted I assume you are on Windows. `subprocess.call` tries to invoke your jpg file as an executable (like *.exe, *.bat etc.) and fails because it isn't an executable. This is not a bug, this is the correct behavior.

If you want to launch the Windows Photo Gallery (or whatever program is set for the *.jpg file extension in your file associations), you can use `os.startfile` like this:

```
import os
os.startfile('/Users/siddarthkrishnan/Desktop/Lion.jpg')
```

Note: this solution works only on Windows.